# Preload audio data on HTML load

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm building an in-browser audio sampler, and I would like to preload many audio files on page load, before any user interaction.

Basically it works like this:

```
audioBuffers = {};
fetch("audio_file_1234.wav")
  .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then((arrayBuffer) =>
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, (buffer) => {
      audioBuffers[1234] = buffer;
    })
  );
```

Problem: in order to call `decodeAudioData` we need an `audioContext` and in order to have an `audioContext` we need user interaction:

> The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.

But I would like to load all the data before the first user interaction.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is a bit misleading. It is absolutely no problem to create an `AudioContext` without a user gesture. You can use it for example to call `decodeAudioData()`.

But the `AudioContext` will most likely be `suspended` which means you need to call `resume()` in response to a user gesture before you can actually play something with that `AudioContext`.

```
$someButton.onclick = () => {
    audioContext.resume();
};
```

Comment: Ok, but does that mean that every website that wants to preload audio now forever needs to tolerate this warning in their dev tools? There must be a workaround to avoid that warning.

Comment: If you really want to get rid of the warning you could use an `OfflineAudioContext` just to decode the audio. The `AudioContext` could then only be created for the playback. However this approach might introduce some unnecessary sample rate conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an audio element in your HTML? If so, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-preload

Comment: No, I don't have <audio> tag elements, instead i'm using Web Audio API audio buffers that I can manipulate more easily with more customization than an HTML5 audio tag.